# Unable to deploy application on Websphere 8.0 due to OutOfMemory error

Tags: websphere

When I start to deploy my application, the build is successful but I get the following error while installing:

---

```
 [exec] JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2013/07/09 13:55:51 - please wait.

 [exec] JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
 [exec] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "deployStartApp_DEV1.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]
 [exec] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried increasing the heap size, but it didn't help. Can anybody help me out? I could not find a solution for deploying on `WebSphere 8.0`

Answer (score 4):

Since I understand you are using wsadmin to do your deployment you might want to use something like:

```
wsadmin.bat -javaoption –Xms256m -javaoption –Xmx768m
```

when calling the wsadmin command.
More on this [here](http://enerosweb.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/websphere-wsadminbat-utility-runnin-out-of-memory/) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/timdp/entry/avoiding_java_lang_outofmemoryerror_when_installing_application_with_wsadmin35?lang=en).